# 90s/00s anime with a kid and his battle robot that he upgrades to fight in arena battles

Tags: story-identification, anime, robots

Anime that I'm pretty sure was dubbed and brought over to NA that I watched in late 90s maybe early 00s. Premise was a kid and his battle robot that he upgraded from time to time to do some kind of arena battles I think? Main robot is on the left and pretty sure he's red normally.

[image: Two humanoid robots in bulky armour pose together on an orange background, left is mainly grey with white undertones and blue highlights with weapons built above the hands, right is white with red highlights]

Comment: You can accept an answer by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons as per the [tour].

Answer (score 5):

Looks like Medabots, the one on the left is this guy https://medabots.fandom.com/wiki/Metabee. Premise is correct from my memory also, definitely dubbed in europe too, same time frame.

ETA - Shown in the US and Europe early 2000s, dubbed, in the robot battles they tended to lose parts to the winning player which they can use to upgrade their own. Robots need a disk that lets them work, you win the battles when it ejects, though the one in the protagonists robot was special, probably experimental which let it be much more alive. He finds it in the river walking home from school.
a link to plot summary https://japaneseanime.fandom.com/wiki/Medabots_(Anime)